# How can I prevent world lighting from passing through objects?

Tags: lighting, world

I'm using world lighting in Blender 3.6.2 by following the tutorial *[Creating 3D Environments For Free And Easily With BlenderKit Addon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S_m_OfsUOdU&t=1s&ab_channel=MKGraphics)*.

However, the light from this world can pass through solid objects like a cube without being blocked. How can I prevent light from passing through objects?

My image:

[image]

Expected:

[image: Expected]

World lighting:

[image: World lighting]

Comment: Are you in Rendered display mode? Could you please share your object?

Comment: @moonboots Yes I'm in Rendered display mode. Here is my project: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZGQ_k-kBi1ZKdpcaaD-2Clu2N0ogNedl/view?usp=sharing . Please help me to check it.

Comment: You are in Eevee render engine, while he's probably in Cycles, in Eevee the HDRI image doesn't seem to project any shadow, therefore your problem here

Comment: @moonboots Thank you very much. Works like a charm after I changed render engine to Cycles, but it's very slow to render.

Comment: You can stay in Eevee but it will need some parameters tweaking, if you switch to Cycles you can also tweak some parameters to make it quicker

Answer (score 1):

- Add **Sun** light and enable **Contact Shadows** under *Object Data properties > Shadow*.
- Add **Irradiance Volume** object and **Bake Indirect Lightning** under *Render Properties > Indirect Lightning*.

[image]

Tips:

- To avoid light rays to penetrate walls add *Solidify* modifier to these objects.
- Dont forget to match HDR's sun light direction with Sun object.

Answer (score 0):

In Eevee, the HDRI image doesn't cast any shadow, you need to switch to Cycles, like in the tutorial you link, if you want your HDRI image to cast shadow. If you want to use Eevee you can still use some tricks like creating a light, use a *Light Path* node for the *World* (so that it stays visible but doesn't enlight the scene), etc...